# Php display contents of pdf

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, pdf

Is it possible to print the contents of a pdf using php ,javascript or jquery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No for the JavaScript/jQuery piece, on the PHP side if you're using a library to read the files then that's an option, [for your PDF options in PHP check out this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/560583/which-is-the-best-pdf-library-for-php).

If you just want to display the content to the user though, just returning the PDF itself and letting their client-side viewer of choice do the work would be my first option.

Comment: the pdf is on the serverside and ijust want to just display the contents of it using php,python or any other utility

Comment: @Rajeev - In that case just return the file to the client, for example: http://www.michiknows.com/2007/03/28/php-nuisance-how-to-stream-pdf-files/

Answer (score 2):

There is a jQuery PDF document viewer based on PDF.js available here:

http://dev.funkynerd.com/projects/jquery-pdfdoc/wiki

It renders the PDF on the client in javascript and so does not require any client-side software other than a relatively modern browser.